# Barcode 128 special character for space

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, barcode

I'm using [Barcode Rendering Framework](http://barcoderender.codeplex.com/) to produce a barcode, but when I try to add text with a space the barcode doesn't get rendered.

Is there a special character that is needed to add a space?

```
<img src="@Url.Barcode("test me", BarcodeSymbology.Code128, 30, 1, true)" />;
```

**EDIT for @a.celiwa**

The documentation was a little difficult to find but it is there. Under Source Code -> VS2010_NET35 -> SampleMvcSite

But Here is the code to get a basic sample to work:

**I  installed Zen Barcode Rendering Framework - Web Compnents from Nuget

Razor

```
@using Zen.Barcode
@using Zen.Barcode.Web
@using Zen.Barcode.Web.Mvc

<div>
    <img src="@Url.Barcode("123456", BarcodeSymbology.Code128, 30, 1, true)" />
</div>
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.Add("BarcodeImaging", new Route("Barcode/{id}", new BarcodeImageRouteHandler()));
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this zen barcode framework in mvc 4 that way:

Controller:

```
using Zen.Barcode;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

        public ActionResult generate_barcode(string txt)
        {

            FileContentResult result;
            //you can use every other barcode type:
            Code128BarcodeDraw bdw = BarcodeDrawFactory.Code128WithChecksum;

            System.Drawing.Image img = bdw.Draw(txt, 50, 1);

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            img.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);

            //HERE you can do other stuff, such as add txt to barcode...

            result = this.File(stream.GetBuffer(), "image/jpeg");

            return result;
        }
```

View:

```
<img src='@Url.Action("generate_barcode", new {txt = "ABCD EFGH" })' alt="" />
```

I'm not shure if this is the best/proper way, but it works for me (and i can add text below barcode)

ps. Can u write how do you use barcode framework? I used to tray this, but it generated only empty imgs... I did this:

> For Mvc: reference Zen.Barcode.Web.dll and optionally
>   lib\Zen.Barcode.Mvc.dll. You can then:    1) Add a barcode image route
>   to your MVC application:    routes.Add("BarcodeImaging", new
>   Route("Barcode/{id}",new BarcodeImageRouteHandler()));    2) Use it
>   with     The HTML helper method will create a URL to return your
>   barcode.

And it creates empty `<img/>`s...
How did you do this?

Comment: Thanks for the response.I actually ended up downloading the source code myself and changing what needed to be changed to get spaces to work. See my edit for the answer to your PS, any questions let me know